# How to place container holding buttons into code

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, containers

I need to have the play buttons in a **separate container** that is **not mixed in with the html**. This is so that the **buttons are able to fade-in**. I did that here where you can see the buttons are fading in.

**Play Buttons Fading In:** https://jsfiddle.net/92fc7w0n/

What I need to do is remove the play buttons from this working code here, and place them in a container.

**Working Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/5r9qkg4s/

The code here is with the play buttons removed.

**Buttons Removed From Working Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/4vtna6kz/

What I need help with is placing this `playButtonContainer` https://jsfiddle.net/92fc7w0n/

Inside this code with the play buttons removed. https://jsfiddle.net/exf86gwL/

It should be **set up like this** in the html.

```
<div class="outer">
</div>

<div class="playButtonContainer">
</div>
```

This is where I am having the most difficulty figuring out how to do. The snippet I provided is of the play buttons fading in while inside a container. That container needs to be placed inside the code where I removed the play buttons from.

**Here:** https://jsfiddle.net/exf86gwL/

How am I able to do that?

**Here was my attempt** at this link: https://jsfiddle.net/jr45bo96/

The buttons fade in, but nothing happens when they are clicked on.

I can't figure out how to get the code to work.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.playButtonContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 290px;
  gap: 10px;
  animation: fadeInButtons 5s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInButtons {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;

  }
}

.thePlay {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  fill: blue;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="playButtonContainer">
  <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <g id="play">
        <title>Play</title>
        <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
        <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
  <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <use href="#play" />
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're having. What's not working with your attempt? Please revise to simplify (you don't need to show so many demos) and explain better.

Comment: The code isn't working when the buttons are clicked on. https://jsfiddle.net/jr45bo96/ The  only thing working in the code is the buttons fading in.

Comment: Are you attaching your click event handlers _after_  you introduce the new elements? You can't do so before.

Comment: It's working the first time..

Comment: The code that is being worked on is the one where the buttons are fading in. This one: https://jsfiddle.net/jr45bo96/ This is the code that is broken, where the play buttons are in a separate container in order for them to be able to fade in.